# Nested apoc iterate with apoc load jdbc returns "cannot conclude with CALL" message

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am calling a nested apoc procedure to iterate the loading of data via jdbc driver from mysql to ingest into neo4j. The statement looks as follows:

```
WITH 'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/schema?user=x&password=x' AS url, 'select * from table' AS query 
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url, query) YIELD row', 'MERGE (e:MYNODE {id:row.id}) SET e.id = row.id', {batchSize:1000, parallel:false})
```

Receiving the following result:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 2, column 1 (offset: 123))
"CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url, query) YIELD row', 'MERGE (e:MYNODE {id:row.id}) SET e.id = row.id', {batchSize:1000, parallel:false})"
 ^
```

Answer (score 4):

1. As the error message says, Cypher does not like you ending a query with a `CALL` clause (unless it is the only clause in the query). You can solve this by just adding a `RETURN` clause to the end of the query, even if you don't care about the result.
2. Cypher also wants you to `YIELD` at least one of the returned values from a `CALL`ed procedure, even if you don't care about it.
3. Your `'CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url, query) YIELD row'` string is not going to automatically use your `url` and `query` variables. You can solve that by using [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

This example solves all 3 issues:

```
WITH
  'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/schema?user=x&password=x' AS url,
  'select * from table' AS query 
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'CALL apoc.load.jdbc($url, $query) YIELD row',
  'MERGE (e:MYNODE {id:row.id}) SET e.id = row.id',
  {batchSize:1000, parallel:false, params:{url: url, query: query}}) YIELD batches
RETURN batches
```