# Load a huge CSV with multiple relationship types

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, bulk-load

I am trying to load a CSV file into a Neo4j database where the file contains different types of edges between nodes. I would like to load all the different types of edges from one file in one query (as opposed to breaking the file into separate files each containing a different type of edge). For instance:

```
Source|Target|Relationship
x1|y1|Creates
x2|y2|Uses
x3|y1|Uses
```

Cypher does not like the following load query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///filename.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (x:Node {name: line.Source})
MERGE (y:Node {name: line.Target})
CREATE (x)-[:line.Relationship]->(y)
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600159/947889), I can use APOC instead as the following:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///filename.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (x:Node {name: line.Source})
MERGE (y:Node {name: line.Target})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(x, line.relationship, y) YIELD rel
RETURN *
```

However, this performs very slowly when run on a large scale (50,000) compared to the first example, and I suspect it is related to `YIELD rel RETURN *`. I am using Neo4j's .NET driver, and executing this query, returns a list of all the edges it has created.

Naively dropping `YIELD` or `RETURN` results in errors such as the following (see [this for some explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58562727/947889)):

> Query cannot conclude with CALL together with YIELD

So, I was wondering how best I can improve the above query, ideally without having to return or yield any of the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a simple string:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///filename.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (x:Node {name: line.Source})
MERGE (y:Node {name: line.Target})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(x, line.relationship, {}, y) YIELD rel
RETURN distinct 'done'
```

What you can also do is to use `PERIODIC IMPORT` to batch your transactions with large CSVs

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///filename.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (x:Node {name: line.Source})
MERGE (y:Node {name: line.Target})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(x, line.relationship, {}, y) YIELD rel
RETURN distinct 'done'
```

Comment: Would not `yield` result in creating the list of relationships, even though you're not returning them to the caller.

Comment: Yes, but that is not a problem

Comment: could you please elaborate? e.g., suppose I've 1 billion relationships, I suppose `yield`ing them all stores them all in the memory, hence the machine running Neo4j requires to have sufficient amount of memory to fit them all. Am I missing something?

Comment: You couldn't really use this for importing billion relationships... but that's why you use batching so you don't run out of memory